# NASM x86 Assembly creating key value tuples

Tags: assembly, x86, tuples, nasm, lookup

I have a portion of a project I'm working on that requires the user to enter a two digit ID number followed by a name string. There will be 5 pairs of these (ID,Name) tuples which I will need to store and then look up by ID.

For example if the user enter 18 for ID and John for the name, when I go into a search phase of the program and user enters 18 as the value to look up, then John will be printed to screen.

I'm not necessarily looking for complete code, but I'm not sure exactly the best way to go about doing this in assembly language. I would appreciate some direction of the best way to do this task so I can start looking into more options.

Comment: Suggestion: Develop a solution in your favorite high-level language first. Try to avoid using any higher level or library features that you will not have available later when converting the solution to assembler.

Comment: There are several ways to do this. If you're positive that the IDs always will be (at most) two decimal digits you could keep a table of 100 string pointers. That would be fast, but wastes some space. Another alternative would be to have an array of ID,pointer pairs, in which you store the pairs in ascending order based on the ID. Insertion would become slow, but lookup is fast and you don't waste space. Or you could store the pairs in a linked list. Some of these would be overkill if you know that there only will be 5 entries, but your teacher may want you to write something that can scale.